# How does the Squarespace iPhone app allow multiple images to be selected from the library?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I've just seen a video of the new [Squarespace iPhone app](http://vimeo.com/7440185) and they appear to allow you to choose multiple images from your library or camera roll.

How have they achieved this, as there's nothing allowing this in the UIImagePickerController docs?

This isn't supported by the SDK, and if they're accessing photos from outside the sandbox and creating their own image picker then how was this app approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can read the images from the camera roll, the sandbox just prohibits writing in this directory. There are a couple of apps in the app store doing this, for instance to access the original image file and to obtain EXIF or other meta data from it. The UIImage provided by the UIImagePicker does not contain this data (for example the location).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, why is this voted up??

Comment: I suggest you read the question and answer again. If you still feel that my answer has nothing to do with the question, feel free to downvote.

Comment: Is it really allowed though? It's not in the docs therefore it will be part of the undocumented SDK. Is there anywhere that explicitly says that just writing outside the sandbox is not allowed? Also, how is this accessible then? Is it via an undocumented framework?